# EJB Singleton - Lock READ method calling a Lock WRITE method of the same instance

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton, ejb

Given a Singleton like this one:

```
@Singleton
public class waitingTimeManager {

    private Map<Integer, Object> waitingTimes;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        waitingTimes = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public boolean shouldWeWait(Integer id) {
        if (waitingTimes.containsKey(id)) {
            boolean wait = someLogic(waitingTimes.get(id));
            if (!wait) {
               // we don't need to wait for it anymore
               stopWaiting(id);
            }
            return wait;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public void stopWaiting(Integer id){
        waitingTimes.remove(id);
    }

}
```

The initial method *shouldWeWait* can be accessed at the same time by several threads. The other *stopWaiting* will need to get a write lock.

Will the call to *stopWaiting* inside *shouldWeWait* try to get a WRITE Lock? or simply execute it as it already got the READ Lock initially?

Comment: AFAIK the `@Lock` on `stopWaiting` is not recognized since you have to invoke it on the business object and not on `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't try to get write lock.

Container job is done within interceptors, wrapping EJB method calls. For example, when stateless BeanA calls your singleton - it does so through proxy, which makes possible the guarantees given by container (retrieving lock, etc.).

But in this case, it's just a normal method call (stopWaiting), not wrapped by proxy, so no place for magic.